# innerHtml in Javascript replace the original content and add new content?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, innerhtml

I use the Javascript with the timer option. In that I added the `innerHtml` text.

```
<?php 
   if(get_option('popup_delay_auto')=='1') { ?> function countDown(i) {
             var int = setInterval(function () {
           document.getElementById("ptechsolinside").innerHTML = "You Must Wait Until the Timer Ends " + i;
           document.getElementById("ptechsolinside").textContent;
           
        i-- || clearInterval(int) || jQuery('#ptechsolfb').stop().fadeOut('medium') ; 
         //if i is 0, then stop the interval
    }, 1000);
}
countDown(<?php echo get_option('popup_template_count');?>);

<?php } ?>
```

I used this code for the timer of 25 seconds after that its shows the content. I added the text as "You Must Wait Until the Timer Ends". When I use the `innerHtml` it replace the original content from the div of `#ptechsolinside` and adds the "You Must Wait Until the Timer Ends" when it comes up. I am not sure what I did wrong. Now I want to show both existing content and current content. How can I do this, is it possible? Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: why don't you just show your text, and set an timer to hide it after 25 seconds ? there's no point refreshing the text if you don't specify the time left in it...

Comment: Do you mean you want to append the text to the innerHTML instead of overwrite it? If so, try changing `.innerHTML = ` to `.innerHTML += `

Comment: that's what should happen. assigning to .innerHTML replaces the **ENTIRE** contents of that node in the DOM tree.